# cd ~user isn't working when user is looked up on LDAP

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ldap

I've configured an Ubuntu server so that it uses an LDAP server for authentication of SSH logins. I've also configured it so that home directories are created automatically when the user logs on.

What doesn't seem to be working though is the lookup of that user's home directory from another user. For example, if I want apache2 to be able to make the user's home directory available, it doesn't work, neither does "cd ~user".

It definitely works for the user when they SSH in - "cd ~" puts them in the right directory.

Am I missing something? Overlooking something in the configuration?

Thanks.

Philip

Comment: The configuration of `/etc/nsswitch.conf`, `/etc/ldap.conf` and perhaps `/etc/nslcd.conf` would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why cd ~user wasn't working but it is now after shutting down the server and starting it up again (it is an EC2 instance so I had stopped it while I didn't need it), suggesting I should have restarted a process or something like that.

As to why apache2 wasn't supporting ~user, I hadn't "sudo a2enmod userdir". Once that was done, it all worked.